# I'm using express nodejs to render a Mailchip API and I am getting this error 'Can't set headers after they are sent'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been getting the above error and I have been looking for a solution for days,I don't know what have I done wrong.Basically I want to send the success page if the response code corresponds to 200 from my API, if not send the failure page. Here is my code.

'''

```
const express = require('express');
const app= express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const https = require('https');
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/signup.html');
});
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    const fname = req.body.fName;
    const lname = req.body.lName;
    const email = req.body.email;

    res.write(fname);
    res.write(lname);
    res.write(email);

    const data = {
        members: [
            {
                email_address:email,
                status: 'subscribed',
                merge_fields:{
                    FNAME: fname,
                    LNAME: lname
                }
            }
        ]
    };



    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const url = 'https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/listId'
    const options = {
       method: 'POST',
       auth:'nhlanhla:API Key'
    };
    const request = https.request(url, options, function(response){
        if(response.statusCode===200){
          res.sendFile(__dirname + '/success.html');
        }else{
          res.sendFile(__dirname + 'failure.html');
        }

        response.on('data', function(data){
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });
   request.write(jsonData);
   request.end()
});
app.post('/failure', function(req, res){
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(port, function(req, res){
    console.log('The server has started');
});
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

Your `request.end()` is being called before you complete your API call to `https://us6.api.mailchimp.com` finishes.

I'm guessing you only need to send `success.html` or `failure.html` based on the result to the API call to `https://us6.api.mailchimp.com`.

If that so, update your code like below:

```js
app.post('/', function(req, res){
    const fname = req.body.fName;
    const lname = req.body.lName;
    const email = req.body.email;

    // res.write(fname);
    // res.write(lname);
    // res.write(email);

    const data = {
        members: [
            {
                email_address:email,
                status: 'subscribed',
                merge_fields:{
                    FNAME: fname,
                    LNAME: lname
                }
            }
        ]
    };



    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const url = 'https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/listId'
    const options = {
       method: 'POST',
       auth:'nhlanhla:API Key'
    };
    https.request(url, options, function(response){
        if(response.statusCode===200){
          res.sendFile(__dirname + '/success.html');
        }else{
          res.sendFile(__dirname + 'failure.html');
        }

        response.on('data', function(data){
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });
   // request.write(jsonData);
   // request.end()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use promises to solve your problem

```
makeRequest(url, options) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            https.request(url, options, function(response){
                if(response.statusCode===200){
                    // better resolve here, unless you need data
                    // resolve(response.statusCode);
                }else{
                    reject(response.statusCode);
                }
                
                response.on('data', function(data){
                    resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

and use it

```
   var jsonData;
   try {
     jsonData = await makeRequest(url, options);
     res.sendFile(__dirname + '/success.html');
   } catch(err){ 
       res.sendFile(__dirname + 'failure.html') 
    }
   request.write(jsonData);
   request.end()
```